# extrack string from rectangular brackets in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

i want to latch a string between brackets and i wondered what is the best way

what do i mean

i got some line in file

```
[307b..3fff] : 00000000000000000;
```

i need to latch `307b` , `3fff` and `00000000000000000`

i try to latch it using regexp , to find the brackets and latch the string inside

```
regexp -nocase -lineanchor -- {^\[\s*\]} $line match 
puts $match
```

how can i latch the value in the brackets , 307b..3fff ?

itamar

Comment: what can be inside the `[]`'s? Are they hex numbers, or can there be any characters other than two dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following solution, `num1`, `num2` and `num3` will hold the values you need:

```
set line {[307b..3fff] : 00000000000000000;}
regexp {\[([^][]*)\.\.([^][]*)]\s*:\s*(\d+)} $line - num1 num2 num3 
puts "Number1: $num1\nNumber2: $num2\nNumber3: $num3"
```

See the [Tcl online demo](https://ideone.com/TT4imL)

The regex matches:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1 ("num1"): any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `\.\.` - two dots
- `([^][]*)` - Group 2 ("num2"): any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a  `]`
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 ("num3"): 1 or more digits

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CjkK0q/1).

Comment: If you need to extract `307b..3fff`, just use [`regexp {\[([^][]*)]} $line - num1`](https://ideone.com/JN82oS).

Answer (score 4):

While there are solutions using regular expressions, they're not the only way to parse that string. The `scan` command is useful too… especially you're after the value as a number and not as hex digit string *per se*.

```
set inputString {[307b..3fff] : 00000000000000000;}

scan $inputString {[%x..%x] : %lx;} v1 v2 v3

puts "$v1->$v2 => $v3"
# Output: 12411->16383 => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Donal's answer, but

```
set inputString {[307b..3fff] : 00000000000000000;}
lassign [regexp -inline -all {[[:xdigit:]]+} $inputString] v1 v2 v3
```

works too (fwiw, it also preserves hexadecimaliality).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\[([0-9a-z]+\.\.[0-9a-z]+)\] * : *([0-9])+;
```

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/q7JuC3r_PFiE_X7P)